# Modified parent theme css, how do I push these changes to the child theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using a theme for my wordpress site and I have created and activated a child theme for best practice re. theme upgrades etc.

I want to modify the theme.css of this theme but the option isn't available to me via the child theme. So instead I have modified the parent themes theme.css. I am noticing though that these changes do not replicate to the child theme.

Is there a way I can do this?

**Edit:**

So the best way of performing this is to enqueue the style sheet:
[developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes](http://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes)

I have now updated my functions.php file as seen below, however the changes I want to see in this css file are not active on the page. Is there any way I can test to see that the css file is indeed enqueued?

```
<?php 

function your_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'); 

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // The below file is the one I wish to enqueue
    // It is stored at /assets/css/luxe-style.min.css within the Parent Theme
    //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/luxe-style.min.css'); 

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', 
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
      array($parent_style), 
      wp_get_theme()->get('Version') 
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_theme_enqueue_styles');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I want to modify the style.css of this theme but the option isnt available to me via the child theme" - Why? What keeps you from editing that file?

Comment: The file isn't there when I look in my child theme via Appearance -> Theme Editor. It only shows two style sheets but not the main css file of the theme nor does it show any of the bootstrap files.

Comment: You can/should create it, in the child theme folder, and enqueue it, following the guidelines here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I have tried to enqueue the file but it doesn't seem to be loading for me, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

In my functions.php inside my child-theme, I only put this, and it works:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_styles' );
function mytheme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; 
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```